# How to use required_unless in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I have gone through the validations in Laravel. I have taken so many validation rules from [Laravel Validations Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#available-validation-rules)

I want to user **required_unless**  rule for following conditions.

```
$rules = array(
        'facebookID' => 'alpha_num',
        'googleID' => 'alpha_num',
        'email' => 'required_unless:facebookID,null|required_unless:facebookID,null|email|max:32',
        'password' => 'required_unless:facebookID,""|required_unless:googleID,""|max:20',            
    );
```

I want to add validation rule of **email and password** is only **required** if signup with facebook or google is not attempted.

I believe we can use **required_unless** or **required_if**

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The laravel validation rule only accept value, that's mean `required_unless:facebookID,null` is evaluated as: the field is required unless facebookID='null'. So it's not a case you would need.

My suggest solution is using require_without_all:

```
'email' => 'required_without_all:facebookID,googleID',
'password' => 'required_without_all:facebookID,googleID'
```

The reference link for you: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-required-without-all

Regards